# Formatting output of Counter

Tags: python

I have used Counter to count the number of occurrence of the list items. I have trouble in displaying it nicely. For the below code,

```
category = Counter(category_list)
print category
```

the following is the output,

```
Counter({'a': 8508, 'c': 345, 'w': 60})
```

I have to display the above result as follows,

```
a 8508
c 345
w 60
```

I tried to iterate over the counter object but I'm unsuccessful. Is there a way to print the output of the Counter operation nicely?

Comment: Do you want the output sorted alphabetically by the key or in descending order based on the value?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question but the answers have already covered both sorted and unsorted ways. I wanted to display the result in descending order based upon the values.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Counter` is essentially a dictionary, thus it has keys and corresponding values - just like the ordinary dictionary.
From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> A Counter is a *dict* subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values.

You can use this code:

```
>>> category = Counter({'a': 8508, 'c': 345, 'w': 60})
>>> category.keys() 
dict_keys(['a', 'c', 'w'])
>>> for key, value in category.items():
...     print(key, value)
... 
a 8508
c 345
w 60
```

However, [you shouldn't rely on the order of keys in dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15479928/2301450).

[`Counter.most_common`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) is very useful. Citing the documentation I linked:

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts **from the
>   most common to the least**. If *n* is not specified, *most_common()* returns
>   all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered
>   arbitrarily.

(emphasis added)

```
>>> category.most_common() 
[('a', 8508), ('c', 345), ('w', 60)]
>>> for value, count in category.most_common():
...     print(value, count)
...
a 8508
c 345
w 60
```

Answer (score 10):

`print` calls `__str__` method of `Counter` class, so you need to override that in order to get that output for print operation.

```
from collections import Counter
class MyCounter(Counter):
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join('{} {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.items())
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> c = MyCounter({'a': 8508, 'c': 345, 'w': 60})
>>> print c
a 8508
c 345
w 60
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not care abut having brackets at the beginning and the end another option is using [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html). It sorts the counter alphabetically for you.

```
import pprint
from collections import Counter

category = Counter({'a': 8508, 'c': 345, 'w': 60})
pprint.pprint(dict(category),width=1)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 8508,
 'c': 345,
 'w': 60}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter({'a': 8508, 'c': 345, 'w': 60})
>>> for key,value in sorted(counter.iteritems()):
...     print key, value
...
a 8508
c 345
w 60
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) and one on [`dict.iteritems`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems).

Comment: Instead of `sorted(counter.iteritems())` you should use `counter.most_common()`

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a nice in-line formatter:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({'a': 8508, 'c': 345, 'w': 60})
cs = sorted(c.items(), key=lambda n: n[1], reverse=True)
print(", ".join(f"{el[1]}× {el[0]}" for el in cs))
```

gives

> 8508× a, 345× c, 60× w