# How to calculate variables from worksheet columns using xlrd?

Tags: python, xlrd, python-collections

I am attempting to calculate all variables of a specific value in a given column from an Excel document. I want to be able to iterate over the column and calculate the total of each instance... e.g. how many students received a grade "A".

Here is what I have so far...

test.xls:

> Name, Class, Grade
>
> James, Math, A
>
> Judy, Math, A
>
> Bill, Social Studies, B
>
> Denice, History, C
>
> Sarah, History, B

Here is my python script

```
import xlrd
from collections import Counter
sh = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls', on_demand = True).sheet_by_index(0) # Open workbook and sheet

 for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    grades = str(sh.cell(rownum, 2).value) # Grab all variables in column 2.
    print Counter(grades.split('\n'))  # Count grades
```

**Expected output:**

> A = 2
>
> B = 2
>
> C = 1

**Actual output:**

> Counter({'Grade': 1})
>
> Counter({'A': 1})
>
> Counter({'A': 1})
>
> Counter({'B': 1})
>
> Counter({'C': 1})
>
> Counter({'B': 1})

As each grade is showing in a different list I have been unable to merge/concatenate lists to get a total. Also it is not in the desired output formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by instantiating a `Counter` and then add grades to it while you iterate:

```
grades_counter = Counter()
mysheet = xlrd.open_workbook('grades.xls').sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(1,mysheet.nrows):
    grades_counter += Counter(str(mysheet.row_values(i)[2]))

print grades_counter
Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1})
```

If you are looking to print the output in a more elegant way, you can do the following:

```
for k,v in grades_counter.items():
    print "{} = {}".format(k,v)
```

You should get:

```
A = 2
C = 1
B = 2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is nearly perfect, thank you! Also to complete the question, I have been able to format the counter using this answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316299/formatting-output-of-counter#20316330

Answer (score 0):

```
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    grades = str(sh.cell(rownum, 2).value) # Grab all variables in column 2.
    print Counter(grades.split('\n'))  # Count grades
```

You are creating a list in every iteration.

You can use list comprehension to a create a single list with all the grades:

```
grades = [str(sh.cell(rownum, 2).value) for rownum in range(sh.nrows)]
print Counter(grades)
```

Or without comprehension :

```
grades = []
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    grades.append(str(sh.cell(rownum, 2).value))

print Counter(grades)
```

You would still need to format the content of `Counter(grades)` to your liking:

```
res = Counter(grades)
for grade, count in res.iteritems():
    print '{} = {}'.format(grade, count)
```

Note that:

1. I'm not using `split`.
2. The output won't be in any particular order, and in fact might change between consecutive runs of the script.