# Collections Counter - How to remove "counter" from output

Tags: python

The output is:
`Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})`
Can I remove the "Counter" word?

```
from collections import Counter

word = "hello"

print(Counter(word))
```

Comment: You can convert a `Counter` back to a normal dictionary, if that's what you mean? It's covered [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm pretty sure the order will be lost in Python < 3.7, though

Comment: @DeepSpace *what* order? `Counter` isn't ordered either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is (at least its `str` representation): `print(Counter('aaabbc'))
# Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316299/formatting-output-of-counter

Comment: @DeepSpace that's an implementation detail that's not even mentioned in the docs, it's because they call `most_common` instead of just `items` [in the `__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L707).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fair enough (I'm a big fan of "that's an implementation detail" :D) but OP should be aware of this fact

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert a `Counter` back into a normal dictionary, just do this:

```
d = dict(Counter(word))
```

Now it'll look as usual when you print it:

```
print(d)
```

It really doesn't make any difference, though. `Counter` *is* a dictionary after all. I guess it's ok if you want it to look pretty when printing it.

Comment: But the order will be lost (at least in Python < 3.7): `print(dict(Counter('aaabbc'))) # {'c': 1, 'a': 3, 'b': 2}`

Comment: @DeepSpace that's ok, you must not count on the order of a dictionary, it's not guaranteed for all Python versions. Besides, that's not a requirement in the question, and anyway `Counter` didn't preserve the order, either.

Comment: Dictionaries are not meant for ordered set of values.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez See my comment to  jonrsharpe. It's an implementation detail of how `Counter.__repr__` is implemented but it is at least worth mentioning.

Comment: @IrfanuddinShafi No, they aren't (usually). **But** when printing `Counter` you **do** get an ordered output (follow the rest of the comments, `Counter.__repr__` is implemented using `.most_common` in most if not all Python implementations). It is at least worth mentioning that when converting to a "normal" `dict` this ordered output will be lost

Comment: @DeepSpace but again, that's not a requirement in the question. The downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez How do you know? OP did not mention it.

Comment: @DeepSpace you've been in SO long enough to know it: if it's not explicitly stated in the question, it's not a requirement, otherwise OP wouldn't have accepted this answer. It's incorrect to assume a non-written requirement, unless explicitly stated. And `Counter` doesn't preserve the input order, so there was no order to preserve in the first place. You're depending on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can pass the object to `json.dumps`. `json` only sees the dictionary, not the subclass

```
from collections import Counter
import json

word = "hello"
c = Counter(word)

print(json.dumps(c))
```

result:

```
{"l": 2, "o": 1, "h": 1, "e": 1}
```

that avoids to create a copy as a basic dictionary just to display it properly. 
More ways to print the contents using just loops on key/values and prints: [Formatting output of Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316299/formatting-output-of-counter)

Another way is to force basic `dict` representation method:

```
print(dict.__repr__(Counter(word)))
```

result:

```
{'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the string `'Counter()'` with the function `strip()`:

```
c = Counter('AA')

print(repr(c).strip('Counter()'))
# {'A': 2}
```

or

```
print(c.__repr__().strip('Counter()')) 
# {'A': 2}
```

Alternatively you can use string slicing. It should be more efficient (according to @jonrsharpe):

```
print(c.__repr__()[8:-1])) 
# {'A': 2}
```

Comment: If you're mangling strings, at that point you might as well do `[8:-1]`; it'd be more efficient.